# WPF bound listBox vertical alignment not working as expected

Tags: wpf, listbox, stackpanel

After reading everything I could find about WPF listbox and stack panel controls, I am still at a loss as to what is causing this behavior. I would like for my listbox to stack the items from the top down without a significant amount of space, however no matter what I do it seems to place a large gap between each one. I have made sure to include the VerticalContentAlignment="Top" property to the listbox and set the vertical alignment of my stack panel so it does not default to stretch. Here is the code:

```
<Grid>

        <ListBox x:Name="listView" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" SelectionMode="Multiple" IsHitTestVisible="True" VerticalContentAlignment="Top">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <UniformGrid Columns="1"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>

            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Content.IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/> 
                    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top"/>
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                                <ContentPresenter/>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>


            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>

                <DataTemplate>

                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,10" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="Black">
                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBoxItem},Path=IsSelected}" BorderBrush="#FF242424" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                            <CheckBox.LayoutTransform>
                                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="4" ScaleY="4" />
                            </CheckBox.LayoutTransform>
                        </CheckBox>                      
                        <Image Source="{Binding Image}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Stretch="None" />
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Test1}" FontSize="22" Margin="5,0,0,3" FontWeight="UltraLight"></TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Test2}" FontSize="11" Foreground="#FF585656" Margin="5,0,0,3" FontWeight="UltraLight"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Test3}" FontSize="11" Foreground="#FF585656" Margin="5,0,0,0" FontWeight="UltraLight"/>
                        </StackPanel>

                    </StackPanel>

                </DataTemplate>


            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
```

And here is the result:

[image]

I added the black background to the stack panel item for troubleshooting purposes to ensure that it is not stretching to the available height.

No matter what I do, it appears to be correctly placing the first list item at the top, but them placing large gaps between all consecutive items. Any ideas?

Comment: The UniformGrid divides the space evenly among the children. Add a `Background` setter in your `ItemContainerStyle` and you'll see that the ListBoxItems are taking up all that white space. If your `VerticalContentAlignment` were `Stretch`, the item content would stretch to fill the ListBoxItems. Actually I think the StackPanel VerticalAlignment would have to be Stretch too. Use a vertically oriented StackPanel in your ItemPanelTemplate if you want the items to fill from the top. That's the default, so you could just remove  the `ItemPanelTemplate`.

Comment: @Ed Plunkett Ugh... So easy... Simply removing the ItemPanelTemplate did it. I can't thank you enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `UniformGrid` in your `ItemsPanelTemplate` divides the available space evenly among the children. Add a Background setter in your ItemContainerStyle, and you'll see that the ListBoxItems are occupying all that white space. Their content is top-aligned, but they themselves are stretched vertically to fill the "cells" their parent, the `UniformGrid`, gives them.

If your `ListBoxItem.VerticalContentAlignment` were `Stretch`, along with the `VerticalAlignment` of the `StackPanel` in the `DataTemplate`, the item content would stretch to fill the `ListBoxItems`. But that's not what you want.

You can use a vertically oriented `StackPanel` in your `ItemPanelTemplate` if you want the items to fill from the top. That's the default that the `ListBox` creates for itself, so if you just remove the `ItemPanelTemplate`, that's what you'll get.